# Save output to array, print first element

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, append

I am trying to save output to an array, and print first element, but nothing is displayed

```
logins = []

for us in c.Win32_LogonSession():
    try:
        for user in us.references("Win32_LoggedOnUser"):
            logins.append(user.Antecedent.Domain, user.Antecedent.Name, sep="\\")
            print(logins[0])
    except:
        pass
```

How to correct this?

EDIT

No exceptions are being raised. If I re-write the code

```
for us in c.Win32_LogonSession():
    try:
        for user in us.references("Win32_LoggedOnUser"):
            print(user.Antecedent.Domain, user.Antecedent.Name, sep="\\")
    except:
        pass
```

It lists all the users

```
DOMAIN\Glowie
DOMAIN\service_account
DOMAIN\service_account
DOMAIN\service_account
DOMAIN\service_account
```

Comment: Obviously because some exception raises in `try` block

Comment: @frostnational --- no exceptions, when I try to print the entire output it works out. See EDIT in original question.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be true, because `.append` accepts exactly one argument and you're trying to put three there.

Comment: @frostnational ---- how do I add all of the arguments into the array if .append doesn't work. I thought the code goes through the loop and adds elements to the array. How do I make user.Antecedent.Domain, user.Antecedent.Name, sep="\\" into a single element?

Comment: Make them a list, then append the resulting list.

Comment: @AndreiHorak --- ok let me try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is final working code

```
user_list = []
for us in c.Win32_LogonSession():
    try:
        for user in us.references("Win32_LoggedOnUser"):
            #print(user.Antecedent.Domain, user.Antecedent.Name, sep="\\")
            user_logins = user.Antecedent.Domain + "\\" + user.Antecedent.Name
            user_list.append(user_logins)

    except:
        pass


userID = user_list[0]
print(userID)
```